# TemplateDoesNotExist at / home_page.html

Tags: django, django-templates

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get the error "TemplateDoesNotExist at / home_page.html". My folder structure is  included in the screenshot below. How do I get my template to display when I run the server?

[Folder Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31N0P.jpg)

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]


This is the Traceback:
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

"/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/ecommerceprojects/views.py", line 17, in home_page
    return render(request, "home_page.html", context)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/melissamalala/PycharmProjects/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 25, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home_page.html
[25/Oct/2018 19:27:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 89057
```

Comment: Post the full traceback, and also highlight the traceback text please

Comment: I have added it

Comment: This is because you are adding home_page.html at wrong place. In your app directory add templates. You can add home_page.html  like  `project/ webapp/ templates/ home_page.html` . The best practice is `project/ webapp/ templates/ webapp/home_page.html` and call the template using webapp/home_page.html

Answer (score 0):

In your templates folder, create a folder with your app-name and put your home_page.html inside of there.

So the structure would look something like this:

```
Project_dir
    app_dir
        templates
            app_dir
                home_page.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the template loaders explicitly?

```
'loaders': [
     'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
]
```

It worked for me